# c# just-return delegate like this {return;}

Tags: c#, delegates

How to create and use delegate like this:

```
    public delegate void MyDel();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDel myDel = delegate { return; };
        Test(myDel);
    }

    static void Test(MyDel myDel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("111");
        myDel?.Invoke();
        Console.WriteLine("222");
    }
```

Output is
111
222

but I'd like to get
111.

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Your delegate represents a function that just returns.  When you invoke it, it will just return (i.e., do nothing of interest).  Then control will return to the place where `Invoke` was called.  You can't do what you are trying to do (call something that causes the caller to return from the call site).  The only way a _callee_ can jump out of a _caller_'s context is by throwing an exception.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

This is very exotic challenge. Unfortunately, I can not give you a complete answer, but I can give the direction of the search. And following article will useful to learn:
[.NET CLR Injection](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time).
It might turn out like this:

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void MyDel();
    static void Main()
    {
        MyDel myDel = delegate
        {
            // Get the method that called this delegate.
            StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
            var method = trace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod();

            // Get opcodes of given method.
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle);
            byte[] ilCodes = method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < ilCodes.Length; i++)
            {
                // Find and replace opcodes to insert a return statement.
                // ...
            }

            // Then inject opcodes back to the original method.
            // ...
        };
        Test(myDel);
    }

    static void Test(MyDel myDel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("111");
        myDel?.Invoke();
        Console.WriteLine("222");
    }
}
```

This is just a guess, not 100% sure it will work. And I know, it's madskills for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really trying to do here.
But in your case, with the current implementation, it is impossible to have `111` only as output. Those three statements will be executed no matter what the *delegate* does.

```
Console.WriteLine("111");
myDel?.Invoke();
Console.WriteLine("222");
```

However if you put the third line that outputs `222` in the delegate body  surrounded with some `if() { ... }` statements, maybe it will print `111` only (when the conditions are not satisfied obviously).